# Projecting different points in an sf table into different UTM projections (using R)?

Tags: r, r-sp, r-sf

I have multiple points in an `sf` object in R, called `pixel.zones` of which I have included a sample below. The actual file has over 100,000 points, but I'll include 2 here to save space :)  Each item in the table has a column specifying the desired projection of the point (I am working in a large area, so different points are in different UTM zones). I want to reproject the coordinates for each point into the corresponding UTM zone.

I know `sf` has `st_transform()`, but I'm not sure how to make it so different points in an sf object have different projections. Any help would be great, preferably using `sf`, but I can change anything into `sp` if need be.

```
pixel.zones=structure(list(id = c("1", "1"), system.index = c(1L, 3534L), 
    b2_allPix = c(6206L, 1524L), b2_cloudfilt_strong = c(6206L, 
    1524L), b2_cloudfilt_weak = c(6206L, 1524L), system.time_start = c(954547200000, 
    954547200000), .geo = c(NA, NA), zone.num = c(7, 6), zone.espg = c(26907, 
    26906), geometry = structure(list(`1` = structure(c(-142.326683967925, 
    67.144791660576), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `2` = structure(c(-147.528084912676, 
    66.2989583273184), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), .Names = c("1", 
    "2"), class = c("sfc_POINT", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(-147.528084912676, 
    66.2989583273184, -142.326683967925, 67.144791660576), .Names = c("xmin", 
    "ymin", "xmax", "ymax"), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
        epsg = 4326L, proj4string = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"), .Names = c("epsg", 
    "proj4string"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), .Names = c("id", 
"system.index", "b2_allPix", "b2_cloudfilt_strong", "b2_cloudfilt_weak", 
"system.time_start", ".geo", "zone.num", "zone.espg", "geometry"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("sf", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Names = c("id", "system.index", "b2_allPix", 
"b2_cloudfilt_strong", "b2_cloudfilt_weak", "system.time_start", 
".geo", "zone.num", "zone.espg"), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", 
"identity"), class = "factor"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps split the data frame and then perform transformation based on different EPSG code accordingly.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

pixel.zones_list <- pixel.zones %>%
  split(f = .$zone.espg) %>%
  map(~st_transform(., crs = unique(.$zone.espg)))
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems like it should work. However, I get an error `Error in map.poly(database, regions, exact, xlim, ylim, boundary, interior,  : 
  no recognized region names`  Am I perhaps missing a package or something?

Comment: @Ana Are you talking about your example dataset or your real-world dataset? I developed this code based on your example, so it would work on your example, but I have no way to know why it cannot work on your real-world dataset.

Comment: I am talking about the example dataset, which is why I was wondering if it was some sort of package issue? I have sf and tidyverse loaded, so I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: I just rebooted R and cleaned out my environment, and it seems to be working! How do I get it out of that list, and back into one data frame?

Comment: One sf object should have one projection unless I misunderstood. What you are asking may not be feasible.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a way to break them up into multiple sf objects (not in list format?). Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can access the list object by index, such as `sf1 <- pixel.zones_list[[1]]`. Or using `assign` to assign list variables with names, but usually `assign` is not recommend as working with list is easier.

Comment: So what I'm trying to create is one large data.frame with pixel coordinates, it doesn't need to be an sf object. So if I were to turn `pixel.zones_list` into just a data.frame, then would there be a way to turn it into one long table?

Comment: Try to use `bind_rows` if this is what you want.

Comment: If I do `x=bind_rows(pixel.zones_list %>% as.data.frame())` then it just puts all the points into one row? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: And just doing `x=bind_rows(pixel.zones_list) ` gives me a list of lists. I'm trying to get it into a data frame situation, where each row in the original sf object is a row in the final data frame.

Comment: `x <- bind_rows(pixel.zones_list)` gave me a data frame. Please refer to the documentation of `bind_rows`. `bind_rows` can and should work on a list of data frames.